# Create two gauges with different needle value in d3

Tags: javascript, html, css

Firstly, i have minimum programming knowledge and just trying it to show something on my website. i need to show two gauges in my page where both will have different needle values. Now i was successful to find a code displaying a gauge in d3 where i was able to set the value. However when when i duplicate the div and the script to show two different gauges, both gauges are being rendered in second div even when i have kept ids for both divs and gauges different. here is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <title>Gauge</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    body {
        font-family:  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 32px;
    }

    #power-gauge g.arc {
        fill: red;
    }

    #power-gauge g.pointer {
        fill: yellow;
        stroke: yellow;
    }
    
    #power-gauge g.label text {
        text-anchor: middle;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        fill: #000;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div> <h1> Sector Prosperity </h1>
</div>
<div id="power-gauge"></div>
    
<script>
var gauge = function(container, configuration) {
    var that = {};
    var config = {
        size                        : 400,
        clipWidth                   : 400,
        clipHeight                  : 270,
        ringInset                   : 20,
        ringWidth                   : 90,
        
        pointerWidth                : 5,
        pointerTailLength           : 0,
        pointerHeadLengthPercent    : 0.85,
        
        minValue                    : 0,
        maxValue                    : 650,
        
        minAngle                    : -90,
        maxAngle                    : 90,
        
        transitionMs                : 750,
        
        majorTicks                  : 600,
        
        labelFormat                 : d3.format(',g'),
        labelInset                  : 100,
        
        arcColorFn                  : d3.interpolateHsl(d3.rgb('#f64e60'), d3.rgb('#41a4fe'))
    };
    var range = undefined;
    var r = undefined;
    var pointerHeadLength = undefined;
    var value = 0;
    
    var svg = undefined;
    var arc = undefined;
    var scale = undefined;
    var ticks = undefined;
    var tickData = undefined;
    var pointer = undefined;

    var donut = d3.layout.pie();
    
    function deg2rad(deg) {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }
    
    function newAngle(d) {
        var ratio = scale(d);
        var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
        return newAngle;
    }
    
    function configure(configuration) {
        var prop = undefined;
        for ( prop in configuration ) {
            config[prop] = configuration[prop];
        }
        
        range = config.maxAngle - config.minAngle;
        r = config.size / 2;
        pointerHeadLength = Math.round(r * config.pointerHeadLengthPercent);

        // a linear scale that maps domain values to a percent from 0..1
        scale = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([0,1])
            .domain([config.minValue, config.maxValue]);
            
        ticks = scale.ticks(config.majorTicks);
        tickData = d3.range(config.majorTicks).map(function() {return 1/config.majorTicks;});
        
        arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(r - config.ringWidth - config.ringInset)
            .outerRadius(r - config.ringInset)
            .startAngle(function(d, i) {
                var ratio = d * i;
                return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
            })
            .endAngle(function(d, i) {
                var ratio = d * (i+1);
                return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
            });
    }
    that.configure = configure;
    
    function centerTranslation() {
        return 'translate('+r +','+ r +')';
    }
    
    function isRendered() {
        return (svg !== undefined);
    }
    that.isRendered = isRendered;
    
    function render(newValue) {
        svg = d3.select(container)
            .append('svg:svg')
                .attr('class', 'gauge')
                .attr('width', config.clipWidth)
                .attr('height', config.clipHeight);
        
        var centerTx = centerTranslation();
        
        var arcs = svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'arc')
                .attr('transform', centerTx); 
        
        arcs.selectAll('path')
                .data(tickData)
            .enter().append('path')
                .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                    return config.arcColorFn(d * i);
                })
                .attr('d', arc);
        
        var lg = svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'label')
                .attr('transform', centerTx);
        lg.selectAll('text')
                .data(ticks)
            //.enter().append('text')
                .attr('transform', function(d) {
                    var ratio = scale(d);
                    var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio *                                                          range);
                    return 'rotate(' +newAngle +') translate(0,' +(config.labelInset - r) +')';
                })
                .text(config.labelFormat);

        var lineData = [ [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0], 
                        [0, -pointerHeadLength],
                        [-(config.pointerWidth / 2), 0],
                        [0, config.pointerTailLength],
                        [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0] ];
        var pointerLine = d3.svg.line().interpolate('monotone');
        var pg = svg.append('g').data([lineData])
                .attr('class', 'pointer')
                .attr('transform', centerTx);
                
        pointer = pg.append('path')
            .attr('d', pointerLine/*function(d) { return pointerLine(d) +'Z';}*/ )
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +config.minAngle + ')');
            
        update(newValue = 430);
        //== undefined ? 0 : newValue);
    }
    that.render = render;
    
    function update(newValue, newConfiguration) {
        if ( newConfiguration  !== undefined) {
            configure(newConfiguration);
        }
        var ratio = scale(newValue);
        var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
        pointer.transition()
            .duration(config.transitionMs)
            .ease('elastic')
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +newAngle +')');
    }
    that.update = update;

    configure(configuration);
    
    return that;
};
</script>

<script>
function onDocumentReady() {
    var powerGauge = gauge('#power-gauge', {
        size: 400,
        clipWidth: 400,
        clipHeight: 400,
        ringWidth: 80,
        maxValue: 650,
        transitionMs: 4000,
    });
    powerGauge.render();
    
    function updateReadings() {
        // just pump in random data here...
        powerGauge.update(Math.random() * 10);
    }
    
    // every few seconds update reading values
    //updateReadings();
    //setInterval(function() {
        //updateReadings();
    //}, 1000);
}

if ( !window.isLoaded ) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        onDocumentReady();
    }, false);
} else {
    onDocumentReady();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i have created another div with id power-gauge2 as well dupliacted the script and changed the id in rendor function var powerGauge = gauge('#power-gauge', { to #power-gauge1 but both gauges are being rendered in div with id #power-gauge1 and that too with same value.

can someone help out in this?

Comment: Can you share the sample which you tried for to show both gauge (two divs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize for `Gauge2` like *powerGauge2* and again render init like `powerGauge2.render()`

See below snippet, I hope this will help you a lot.

```js
var gauge = function (container, configuration) {
    var that = {};
    var config = {
        size: 400,
        clipWidth: 400,
        clipHeight: 270,
        ringInset: 20,
        ringWidth: 90,

        pointerWidth: 5,
        pointerTailLength: 0,
        pointerHeadLengthPercent: 0.85,

        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 650,

        minAngle: -90,
        maxAngle: 90,

        transitionMs: 750,

        majorTicks: 600,

        labelFormat: d3.format(',g'),
        labelInset: 100,

        arcColorFn: d3.interpolateHsl(d3.rgb('#f64e60'), d3.rgb('#41a4fe'))
    };
    var range = undefined;
    var r = undefined;
    var pointerHeadLength = undefined;
    var value = 0;

    var svg = undefined;
    var arc = undefined;
    var scale = undefined;
    var ticks = undefined;
    var tickData = undefined;
    var pointer = undefined;

    var donut = d3.layout.pie();

    function deg2rad(deg) {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }

    function newAngle(d) {
        var ratio = scale(d);
        var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
        return newAngle;
    }

    function configure(configuration) {
        var prop = undefined;
        for (prop in configuration) {
            config[prop] = configuration[prop];
        }

        range = config.maxAngle - config.minAngle;
        r = config.size / 2;
        pointerHeadLength = Math.round(r * config.pointerHeadLengthPercent);

        // a linear scale that maps domain values to a percent from 0..1
        scale = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([0, 1])
            .domain([config.minValue, config.maxValue]);

        ticks = scale.ticks(config.majorTicks);
        tickData = d3.range(config.majorTicks).map(function () { return 1 / config.majorTicks; });

        arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(r - config.ringWidth - config.ringInset)
            .outerRadius(r - config.ringInset)
            .startAngle(function (d, i) {
                var ratio = d * i;
                return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
            })
            .endAngle(function (d, i) {
                var ratio = d * (i + 1);
                return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
            });
    }
    that.configure = configure;

    function centerTranslation() {
        return 'translate(' + r + ',' + r + ')';
    }

    function isRendered() {
        return (svg !== undefined);
    }
    that.isRendered = isRendered;

    function render(newValue) {
        svg = d3.select(container)
            .append('svg:svg')
            .attr('class', 'gauge')
            .attr('width', config.clipWidth)
            .attr('height', config.clipHeight);

        var centerTx = centerTranslation();

        var arcs = svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'arc')
            .attr('transform', centerTx);

        arcs.selectAll('path')
            .data(tickData)
            .enter().append('path')
            .attr('fill', function (d, i) {
                return config.arcColorFn(d * i);
            })
            .attr('d', arc);

        var lg = svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'label')
            .attr('transform', centerTx);
        lg.selectAll('text')
            .data(ticks)
            //.enter().append('text')
            .attr('transform', function (d) {
                var ratio = scale(d);
                var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
                return 'rotate(' + newAngle + ') translate(0,' + (config.labelInset - r) + ')';
            })
            .text(config.labelFormat);

        var lineData = [[config.pointerWidth / 2, 0],
        [0, -pointerHeadLength],
        [-(config.pointerWidth / 2), 0],
        [0, config.pointerTailLength],
        [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0]];
        var pointerLine = d3.svg.line().interpolate('monotone');
        var pg = svg.append('g').data([lineData])
            .attr('class', 'pointer')
            .attr('transform', centerTx);

        pointer = pg.append('path')
            .attr('d', pointerLine/*function(d) { return pointerLine(d) +'Z';}*/)
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' + config.minAngle + ')');

        update(newValue = 430);
        //== undefined ? 0 : newValue);
    }
    that.render = render;

    function update(newValue, newConfiguration) {
        if (newConfiguration !== undefined) {
            configure(newConfiguration);
        }
        var ratio = scale(newValue);
        var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
        pointer.transition()
            .duration(config.transitionMs)
            .ease('elastic')
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' + newAngle + ')');
    }
    that.update = update;

    configure(configuration);

    return that;
};
</script>

<script>
function onDocumentReady() {
    var powerGauge = gauge('#power-gauge', {
        size: 400,
        clipWidth: 400,
        clipHeight: 400,
        ringWidth: 80,
        maxValue: 650,
        transitionMs: 4000,
    });
    var powerGauge2 = gauge('#power-gauge2', {
        size: 400,
        clipWidth: 400,
        clipHeight: 400,
        ringWidth: 80,
        maxValue: 100,
        transitionMs: 4000,
    });

    powerGauge.render();
    powerGauge2.render();

    function updateReadings() {
        // just pump in random data here...
        powerGauge.update(Math.random() * 10);
        powerGauge2.update(Math.random() * 2);
    }

    // every few seconds update reading values
    //updateReadings();
    //setInterval(function() {
    //updateReadings();
    //}, 1000);
}

if (!window.isLoaded) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        onDocumentReady();
    }, false);
} else {
    onDocumentReady();
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 32px;
}
#power-gauge g.arc{
    fill: red;
}
#power-gauge g.pointer {
    fill: yellow;
    stroke: yellow;
}
#power-gauge g.label text {
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    fill: #000;
}

#power-gauge2 g.arc{
    fill: greenyellow;
}
#power-gauge2 g.pointer {
    fill: orange;
    stroke: orange;
}
#power-gauge2 g.label text {
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    fill: #000;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <h1> Sector Prosperity </h1>
</div>

<div style="display: flex;">
    <div id="power-gauge"></div>
    <div id="power-gauge2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work properly meaning should be able to render gauge by using two div with unique id. Please check below sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=320" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <title>Gauge</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
  <style>
     body {
     font-family:  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
     margin: 32px;
     }
     #power-gauge g.arc {
     fill: red;
     }
     #power-gauge g.pointer {
     fill: yellow;
     stroke: yellow;
     }
     #power-gauge g.label text {
     text-anchor: middle;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: bold;
     fill: #000;
     }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
     <h1> Sector Prosperity </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="power-gauge"></div>
  <div id="power-gauge1"></div>
  <script>
     var gauge = function(container, configuration) {
         var that = {};
         var config = {
             size                        : 400,
             clipWidth                   : 400,
             clipHeight                  : 270,
             ringInset                   : 20,
             ringWidth                   : 90,
             
             pointerWidth                : 5,
             pointerTailLength           : 0,
             pointerHeadLengthPercent    : 0.85,
             
             minValue                    : 0,
             maxValue                    : 650,
             
             minAngle                    : -90,
             maxAngle                    : 90,
             
             transitionMs                : 750,
             
             majorTicks                  : 600,
             
             labelFormat                 : d3.format(',g'),
             labelInset                  : 100,
             
             arcColorFn                  : d3.interpolateHsl(d3.rgb('#f64e60'), d3.rgb('#41a4fe'))
         };
         var range = undefined;
         var r = undefined;
         var pointerHeadLength = undefined;
         var value = 0;
         
         var svg = undefined;
         var arc = undefined;
         var scale = undefined;
         var ticks = undefined;
         var tickData = undefined;
         var pointer = undefined;
     
         var donut = d3.layout.pie();
         
         function deg2rad(deg) {
             return deg * Math.PI / 180;
         }
         
         function newAngle(d) {
             var ratio = scale(d);
             var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
             return newAngle;
         }
         
         function configure(configuration) {
             var prop = undefined;
             for ( prop in configuration ) {
                 config[prop] = configuration[prop];
             }
             
             range = config.maxAngle - config.minAngle;
             r = config.size / 2;
             pointerHeadLength = Math.round(r * config.pointerHeadLengthPercent);
     
             // a linear scale that maps domain values to a percent from 0..1
             scale = d3.scale.linear()
                 .range([0,1])
                 .domain([config.minValue, config.maxValue]);
                 
             ticks = scale.ticks(config.majorTicks);
             tickData = d3.range(config.majorTicks).map(function() {return 1/config.majorTicks;});
             
             arc = d3.svg.arc()
                 .innerRadius(r - config.ringWidth - config.ringInset)
                 .outerRadius(r - config.ringInset)
                 .startAngle(function(d, i) {
                     var ratio = d * i;
                     return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
                 })
                 .endAngle(function(d, i) {
                     var ratio = d * (i+1);
                     return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
                 });
         }
         that.configure = configure;
         
         function centerTranslation() {
             return 'translate('+r +','+ r +')';
         }
         
         function isRendered() {
             return (svg !== undefined);
         }
         that.isRendered = isRendered;
         
         function render(newValue) {
             svg = d3.select(container)
                 .append('svg:svg')
                     .attr('class', 'gauge')
                     .attr('width', config.clipWidth)
                     .attr('height', config.clipHeight);
             
             var centerTx = centerTranslation();
             
             var arcs = svg.append('g')
                     .attr('class', 'arc')
                     .attr('transform', centerTx); 
             
             arcs.selectAll('path')
                     .data(tickData)
                 .enter().append('path')
                     .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                         return config.arcColorFn(d * i);
                     })
                     .attr('d', arc);
             
             var lg = svg.append('g')
                     .attr('class', 'label')
                     .attr('transform', centerTx);
             lg.selectAll('text')
                     .data(ticks)
                 //.enter().append('text')
                     .attr('transform', function(d) {
                         var ratio = scale(d);
                         var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio *                                                          range);
                         return 'rotate(' +newAngle +') translate(0,' +(config.labelInset - r) +')';
                     })
                     .text(config.labelFormat);
     
             var lineData = [ [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0], 
                             [0, -pointerHeadLength],
                             [-(config.pointerWidth / 2), 0],
                             [0, config.pointerTailLength],
                             [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0] ];
             var pointerLine = d3.svg.line().interpolate('monotone');
             var pg = svg.append('g').data([lineData])
                     .attr('class', 'pointer')
                     .attr('transform', centerTx);
                     
             pointer = pg.append('path')
                 .attr('d', pointerLine/*function(d) { return pointerLine(d) +'Z';}*/ )
                 .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +config.minAngle + ')');
                 
             update(newValue = 430);
             //== undefined ? 0 : newValue);
         }
         that.render = render;
         
         function update(newValue, newConfiguration) {
             if ( newConfiguration  !== undefined) {
                 configure(newConfiguration);
             }
             var ratio = scale(newValue);
             var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
             pointer.transition()
                 .duration(config.transitionMs)
                 .ease('elastic')
                 .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +newAngle +')');
         }
         that.update = update;
     
         configure(configuration);
         
         return that;
     };
  </script>
  <script>
     function onDocumentReady() {
         var powerGauge = gauge('#power-gauge', {
             size: 400,
             clipWidth: 400,
             clipHeight: 400,
             ringWidth: 80,
             maxValue: 650,
             transitionMs: 4000,
         });
         powerGauge.render();
         
          var powerGauge1 = gauge('#power-gauge1', {
             size: 400,
             clipWidth: 400,
             clipHeight: 400,
             ringWidth: 80,
             maxValue: 500,
             transitionMs: 4000,
         });
         powerGauge1.render();
         
         function updateReadings() {
             // just pump in random data here...
             powerGauge.update(Math.random() * 10);
         }
         
         // every few seconds update reading values
         //updateReadings();
         //setInterval(function() {
             //updateReadings();
         //}, 1000);
     }
     
     if ( !window.isLoaded ) {
         window.addEventListener("load", function() {
             onDocumentReady();
         }, false);
     } else {
         onDocumentReady();
     }
  </script>
```